# Routing request from public ip

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

so first here is the architecture i'm planning :

The question is simple : Is that is possible and how manage routing in HyperV to route the 443 port on both VM or better on the right vm ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say public ip is 1.1.1.1, private ip of the hyper-v host is 2.2.2.2, vm1 3.3.3.3, vm2 4.4.4.4.

If you want to route 1.1.1.1:443 to just 2.2.2.2, then your firewall rules would do nat/port redirection to get it there. 
If you want to route 1.1.1.1:443 to 3.3.3.3, again it is firewall rules.

Hyper-v does allow vlan tagging so you can bind the public IP straight into a VM even if the Hyper-V host is on a private IP (assuming your network infrastructure allows)

If you are trying to direct 1.1.1.1:443 to 3.3.3.3:443 if it sharepoint requests, or 4.4.4.4:443 if it is an Apache request, well that isn't something Hyper-V (or any VM platform) can do. You can probably get it working using Squid to intercept the traffic and direct the request based on the incoming domain, but that requires another host in front of your two webservers.